# Flex responder onResult, onFault

Tags: apache-flex

i want to create a class, to get a reponse from amfphp services.

There is my code.

```
public class remoteReporting
{
    var myService:NetConnection;
    var RES;

    public function remoteReporting()
        {
            myService = new NetConnection();
            myService.objectEncoding = ObjectEncoding.AMF0;
            myService.connect("../../Amfphp/");
        }
    public function call(fonction:String,parameters)
        {   
            myService.call(fonction,new Responder(RESULT),parameters);
        }

    private function RESULT(res:Object):void{
                    RES=res;
        Alert(String(res));
    } 

    public function get()
        {
            Alert.show(String(RES));
        }
}
```

When i write:

```
Remote = new remoteReporting();
Remote.call("ExampleService.returnOneParam","var1");
```

Here Alert of function Result, show a message ok,
But the Alert of get function dont show any things .

I dont know why ! can u help me !!

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues.  First, Isn't [get a reserved word](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#get) of sorts?  It is used to create the getter half of a getter/setter properties on your component.

When you do this:

```
public function get()
{
    Alert.show(String(RES));
}
```

It looks incomplete to me.  Usually we would do something like this:

```
public function get myProperty():Object
{
    Alert.show(String(RES));
}
```

second, the RES variable is not a complete variable definition:

```
var RES;
```

You didn't define the type.  Try something like this:

```
var RES : Object
```

I suspect that the first is your problem; but I also suspect you either have code that doesn't compile or you have cut out too much of the code before posting here.

You should consider renaming the function to see if it gives you a resolution.  If not, you should consider putting a debug statement in your code and verifying that the method actually runs.  It is not obvious to me, based on the code you provided that the 'get()' method is ever explicitly called, so I'm not sure why it would ever run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you have amfphp set up but you need to connect to the gateway.php file in amfphp.

```
myService.connect("../../Amfphp/gateway.php");
```

That is assuming you're using the default amfphp file names and .htaccess - your setup may be different.

Also your RESULT function Alert call isn't correct - it should be Alert.show(String(res)) not Alert(String(res));

Comment: No i use Amfphp 2.0, and prob isn't here, because i get Alert showing response from a service.

My prob, is how to save the resutl in a var, and use it after.

Comment: it should be Alert.show(String(res)) not Alert(String(res));

Yes, it's just error typing :D

Comment: can you post more of your code - you show instantiating the class but I don't see the call to the get() function anywhere.

Comment: I dont have right to anwser to my question.
Ok all it's right, on main

    Remote = new remoteReporting();
    Remote.call("ExampleService.returnOneParam",new Array("v1","v2");
    var resultat = Remote.get();
    Alert.show(String(resultat ));//Alert 2

Alert 1, is on RESULT function, and return V1,V2
But Alert 2 dont return any things.

Comment: My only prob, is how to save result from onRESULT function, in a var ?!